# SQL Server query : how to use left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(a.U, '') AS U, 
    COALESCE(a.N, '') AS N,
    COALESCE (a.J, '')AS J,
    DATENAME(mm, a.P) AS Month,
    DATENAME(yyyy, a.P) AS Year,
    COALESCE(SUM(a.T), 0)  AS Total,
    COALESCE(SUM(b.Pa), 0) AS Cr,
    COALESCE(SUM(a.T), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(b.Pa), 0) AS TPa    
FROM 
    t1 AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         U, N, SUM(Cr)
     FROM
         t2 
     WHERE 
         U IS NOT NUll AND N IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
         U, N) AS b ON a.U = b.U AND a.N = b.N
WHERE 
    a.L IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    a.U, a.N, a.J,
    DATENAME(mm, a.P), DATENAME(yyyy, a.P)
ORDER BY 
    Month, Year DESC
```

and this query produces the following output:

```
+----+-------+---+--------+-------+---------+------+--------+
| U  | N     | J |  Month | Year  | Total   |  Cr  |  Tpa   |
+----+-------+---+--------+-------+---------+------+--------+
| 2B | Mark  | a | April  | 2016  | 1500    |  0   | 1500   |
| 2D | Jhon  | b | April  | 2016  | 100     | 4300 | -4200  |
| 2D | Jhon  | a | April  | 2016  | 2000    | 4300 | -2300  |
| 3A | Van   | a | April  | 2016  | 1500    | 7000 | -5500  |
| 2D | Jhon  | a | May    | 2016  | 500     | 4300 | -3800  |
| 3A | Van   | a | May    | 2016  | 1200    | 7000 | -5800  |
+----+-------+---+--------+-------+---------+------+--------+
```

How about SQL query if I want to produce this output instead:

```
+----+-------+---+--------+-------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| U  | N     | J |  Month | Year  | Total   |  Cr  |  Tpa   | R     |
+----+-------+---+--------+-------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| 2B | Mark  | a | April  | 2016  | 1500    |  0   |  0     | 1500  |
| 2D | Jhon  | b | April  | 2016  | 100     | 4300 | -4200  |  0    |
| 2D | Jhon  | a | April  | 2016  | 2000    | 4200 | -2200  |  0    |
| 3A | Van   | a | April  | 2016  | 1500    | 7000 | -5500  |  0    |
| 2D | Jhon  | a | May    | 2016  | 500     | 2200 | -1700  | -1700 |
| 3A | Van   | a | May    | 2016  | 1200    | 5500 | -4300  | -4300 |
+----+-------+---+--------+-------+---------+------+--------+-------+
```

At first, (focus on table rows 1,2,4) c column value is obtained from the query line 12-16. then in table row 3 (table row 3 has U and the same N as a table row 2), the value of c obtained from the absolute value:

from Total(line 2)-Cr(line 2). in other words, column C obtained from ABS(Tpa) which previously had U and the same N (group by U and N).

C column is obtained from the ABS (Tpa) which previously had U and the same N (group by U and N).

The value in the column Tpa is obtained from column Total-Cr. 
If Total-Cr> 0, then Tpa = 0 and R = Total-Cr but if Total-Cr <= 0, then Tpa = Total-Cr and columns R = 0.

R values in the table rows 5 and 6 is the result of Total-Cr. This condition occurs if a table row is the last row in the table (group by U and N).

Comment: What does prevent you from just adding `,CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(a.T), 0) > COALESCE(SUM(b.Pa), 0) THEN  COALESCE(SUM(a.T), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(b.Pa) ELSE 0 END as R` to your select list?

Comment: Could you add sample data for your tables and update the expected output based on the sample?  This would give us something we can reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding this type of task may be easily solved with analytic functions like LAG/LEAD and calculating running total with SUM(...) over (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...).

Unfortunately these options are available only starting from SQL Server 2012. So I tried to make a more complex query but that should run even on earlier version (tried on 2008).

Here is the query.

I generated values in common table expressions (CTE) t1, t2.

T3 mainly mimics your query. Just added row_number() to uniquely identify rows within group and also to find last record in a group.

Finally, t4 has new calculations.

```
with 
t1 as 
(
    select '2B' as U, 'Mark' as N, 'a' as J, '2016-04-01' as P, 1500 as T, 1 as L union all 
    select '2D' as U, 'Jhon' as N, 'b' as J, '2016-04-01' as P, 100 as T, 1 as L union all 
    select '2D' as U, 'Jhon' as N, 'a' as J, '2016-04-04' as P, 2000 as T, 1 as L union all 
    select '2D' as U, 'Jhon' as N, 'a' as J, '2016-05-05' as P, 500 as T, 1 as L union all 
    select '3A' as U, 'Van' as N, 'a' as J, '2016-04-05' as P, 1500 as T, 1 as L union all 
    select '3A' as U, 'Van' as N, 'a' as J, '2016-05-05' as P, 1200 as T, 1 as L
),

t2 as 
(
    select '2B' as U,'Mark' as N, 0 as Cr union all
    select '2D' as U,'Jhon' as N, 4300 as Cr union all
    select '3A' as U,'Van' as N, 7000 as Cr
),

t3 as 
(
    SELECT 
        COALESCE(a.U, '') AS U, 
        COALESCE(a.N, '') AS N,
        COALESCE (a.J, '')AS J,
        DATENAME(mm, a.P) AS Month,
        DATENAME(yyyy, a.P) AS Year,
        COALESCE(SUM(a.T), 0)  AS Total,
        COALESCE(SUM(b.Pa), 0) AS Cr,
        --COALESCE(SUM(a.T), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(b.Pa), 0) AS TPa, 
        row_number() over (partition by a.U, a.N order by J desc, DATENAME(mm, a.P)) rn,
        row_number() over (partition by a.U, a.N order by J , DATENAME(mm, a.P) desc) rn_last
    FROM 
        t1 AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT 
             U, N, SUM(Cr) as Pa
         FROM
             t2 
         WHERE 
             U IS NOT NUll AND N IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY 
             U, N) AS b ON a.U = b.U AND a.N = b.N
    WHERE 
        a.L IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        a.U, a.N, a.J,
        DATENAME(mm, a.P), DATENAME(yyyy, a.P)
)

,t4 as (
    select cte1.*
    ,sum(cte2.Total) Cum_Total -- running total
    ,cte1.Cr - sum(cte2.Total) as Cr_Next
    from t3 cte1
    inner join t3 cte2 on cte1.U = cte2.U and cte1.N = cte2.N and cte1.rn >= cte2.rn
    group by 
    cte1.U, cte1.N, cte1.J, cte1.Month, cte1.Year, cte1.Total, cte1.Cr, cte1.rn, cte1.rn_last
) 

select U,N,J,Month,Year,Total,Cr_New as Cr,
case when Total - Cr_New > 0 then 0 else Total - Cr_New end as Tpa,
case when rn_last = 1 then Total - Cr_New else 0 end R
from
(
    select cte1.* 
    , case when cte1.rn =1 then cte1.Cr else cte2.Cr_Next end as Cr_New
    from t4 as cte1
    left join t4 cte2 on cte1.U = cte2.U and cte1.N = cte2.N and cte1.rn = cte2.rn +1
) t
order by 1,2,3 desc
```

It produces the exact result as desired.